# Drop Down List in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to build drop down list on my page. I t purpose is to update prices on my page dependent from chosen currency, so if user will select $ in DDL this will update prices on page to $, If user choose £ this will display prices in £. Prices (in $ and £) for my products are stored in database.

Any tips where to go with it?

Cheers guys

---

Thanks for response @drywoods
so far I got this: 
in index file

```
@Html.DropDownList("Currency", 
                   new SelectList(ViewBag.CurrencyList, "Key", "Value"), 
                   new { Class = "ddlStyle" }
                   )
```

---

and controller:

```
ViewBag.CurrencyList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> 
                                  { 
                                      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pound", "£")
                                      , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dollar", "$")
                                      , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("euro", "€")
                                  };
            GetLoadedMVC.Models.CurrencyModel model = new GetLoadedMVC.Models.CurrencyModel();
            return View();
```

So I got ddl on my page but it doesn't do anything yet.
Where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me this a simple problem.
Lets break it down into small parts:

1 - you need a combo box or something else for the user change the currency:

```
$("#CurrencyId").change( function() {..... }
```

In this Jquery code you can for example post a form where you have an action(controller) that receives the CurrencyId.

2- In this action(controller) you can save this value on a cookie or on session or in the user database entry.

3- Note: for the "first" time this value needs to be initialized by a default value: example: id 2 means € (euro).

4- Now when you query the DB to retrieve the "objects" with some value.
For simplifying the operations: keep the same currency in each one of them, and write the currency used in that entry:  example:

Name[TV LCD Philips], Cost[100], CurrencyId[1] where 1 means $

5 - You need a service/method where you can convert the amount of one currency to other currency.

6 - Now, in the controller or service or somewhere u need to call this service/method of converting per each element on your list.

Do you get the idea?